# How to pass flashVars in to Flash and then back out as a query string

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, query-string, flashvars

I am asking this question as a complete Flash novice, so please do point out if I'm doing anything wrong here (I suspect I am).

I have a Flash MPU size animation with a link in it which has been created by using a full sized transparent layer as a button (is that the correct way) with the following ActionScript:

```
on(release){
  getURL("/account/", "_self")
}
```

What I would like to do is pass some flashVars in to the Flash and then append them as a query string. I have tried a method like this:

```
on(release){
  var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
  getURL("/account/?test="+String(paramObj["test"]), "_self")
}
```

Two things. Firstly I don't think that is the correct way to retrieve the flashVar so I need a bit of help in that respect.

The second problem is that the relative URL being linked to is stripping out the entire query string - so I don't event get "/account/?test=undefined". So how do I actually append the query string to the URL?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Kind of. It helped with regards to accessing the FlashVar in the Flash ActionScript (a lot more simple than whatever I was trying to do before!). But I'm still unsure about how to add a query string to a relative link in Flash. For now I've worked around that issue so it's not a major problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I used Flashvars before in AS2

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.xmlPath = "/themixer/flash/mixerplayer.xml";

    // Rest of Flash code here

</script>
```

### ActionScript-2

```
var xmlFile:String = xmlPath;
```

Then you can do whatever with xmlPath or whatever var you want to call it :)
The XML file can be a string like in your case.